# ScrollView setOverScrollMode replacement in API < 9

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, replace, android-overscoll

From documentation, [ScrollView.setOverScrollMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29) is available in API from version 9

What can I use in API version 7 and 8 as replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overscrolling hints didn't exist pre-gingerbread. So, aside from rolling your own, there's no replacement.